# Parallax with CSS only: adapt scrolling speed of foreground and background so that they both reach bottom at the same time

Tags: css, scroll, parallax

I am at the very beginning of my coding journey, and I am required to work on my current project with HTML and CSS exclusively. The task is to create a simple one-pager website with `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` and play around with CSS a bit. Being a challenge enthusiast with more than enough free time, I took upon myself to add parallax to my one-pager. I have no regrets - yet.

I think that I have understood the broad lines, however I have not quite grasped the deep mechanics of it. I managed to build something that kind of works by tweaking the code from [this video by Red Stapler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln5BWnYMSQA). You can find my work in progress [here on CopePen](https://codepen.io/massart-val/pen/mdPqzPP). I know that it is ugly but I really wanted to learn parallax before styling the content (the hard part before the easy part).

As you will see if you check out my pen, I commented out the original `background-image` and replaced it with a `linear-gradient`. The dimensions of my `background-image` are 1280px*960px, but I would rather display it with a height of 200vh. I have also thought of clipping every `article` to create visual balance and shorten the page (I was initially going for 200vh of total height, hence the dimensions of the `background-image`).

**Here is my question.** How do I properly calibrate the parallax so that my foreground height corresponds to my background height? More specifically, *how do I adapt the scrolling speed so that the foreground and background reach their respective bottoms at the same time*? And is it compatible with my idea of clipping/unclipping parts of the content (which would necessitate that the scrolling speed adapts to the varying foreground height)?

I have a feeling that there's something to try with those two properties`z-index: -1;` `transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);` since the guy in the video explained that elements with different indexes will scroll at different speed, but I have spent the last couple of hours googling in every direction without finding an answer. Or maybe I read it countless times but it just went over my head.

Comment: The tutorial you posted shares the sorce code, why don't you start from there? https://redstapler.co/css-parallax-scrolling-effect/

Comment: Well it is the source code to replicate what he showed in the video, which is what I did to begin with (the only difference being that I replicated it by hand while watching the video instead of copy-pasting the source code). But this is not what my question is about. 

What I was asking is how do I synchronise the scrolling speed of my foreground and my background so that they both reach their bottom at the same time.